# Source code for login function and forms authentatication that uses c# in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, authentication

Please could anyone help me to provide the source code of the log-in function and introduce a way where the user gains access to either the employee, supervisor or admin homepage.

Comment: Extreme lack of effort to solve the problem!

Comment: Many tutorials over there and even default ASP.NET project template offers a basic infrastructure for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this

[Simple login form example in asp.net Check Username and Password availability in database](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/12/how-to-create-simple-login-form-using.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class Authorization
        {
            public string result { get; set; }

        }

        public class UserAuthorization
        {
            public string userName { get; set; }
            public string password { get; set; }
            public string helpText { get; set; }

        }

        GetDataAPI GetData = new GetDataAPI();

  /// <summary>
  /// 
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="userAuth"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
       public HttpResponseMessage ValidateUser(UserAuthorization userAuth)
        {
            Authorization auth = new Authorization();
            string Result = Convert.ToString(GetData.IsLogin(userAuth.userName, userAuth.password));
            auth.result = Result;
            string response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(auth);
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage()
            {

                Content = new StringContent(response)
            };
            return resp;
        }
```

Just specify the connection string and send the response to front end.

You can set the different integer values for the employee, supervisor or admin and then redirect the user to the page of corresponding authenticity.